# How do I use a custom xml ruleset for sonarLint with JetBrains Rider?

Tags: xml, rider, sonarlint

I have a xml-file which defines custom sonar lint coding guidelines, and I need to use it within my JetBrains Rider IDE for work.

However, I have no idea on how to embed this file so that sonar lint uses those custom rules and not the standard ones.

I would like to know how I can achieve this and how I can make sure that it uses those rules.

I have already tried to simply copy the sonarlint.xml file to the following locations:

C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\Rider\options
C:\Users\user.sonarlint

I could not notice any differences, so I am not really sure if it works.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in standalone mode. However, you can use custom rules if you are in connected mode to a SonarQube server, and a custom plugin including your rules is installed on it.

Comment: But how to do this in eclipse, can you explain the steps please